# Excel extract text between identical characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to extract the date from the following text:

`Thu 11/29/18`

I was thinking to use MID function however the length of the month can change depending on the month (e.g. 1 vs 10). Likewise the day starting index and ending index are variable values and depend on the same character '/' to determine its start and end. How might I differentiate the first '/
' from the last '/'?

Comment: Your question title and body don't go together.  If you want to extract the date, `FIND` the first space.  If you want to extract the month number, extract the digits between the first space and the first slash.

Comment: What have you tried? There are myriad sites online (and SE too) explaining how to extract text between delimiters (of any location), take a search around and let us know specifically what you're trying, and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to convert the date then follow Gary's students advice or the plethora of other answers on how to convert a date from TEXT to a DATE or a date from this format to that format.

If you are truly looking for any  example of retrieving the text between the first two sets of identical numbers, you could use a formula such as

```
=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1)+1)-FIND("/",A1)-1)
```

[image: POC]

Answer (score 0):

With text in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99))
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. we grab the part of the string after the space:  `11/29/18`
2. `DATEVALUE()` changes this to a true Excel date.

Comment: With DATEVALUE(), doesn't the text date format have to match your system date format?